# How to use cleaver.js with vue-form-generator

Tags: vue.js

I use [VueFormGenerator](https://github.com/vue-generators/vue-form-generator) with cleaver.js, after adding the following code(according to the documentation) i get the error "Unknown custom element: ".
cleaver.js has installed via npm.

```
{
  type: "cleaver",
  inputType: "text",
  label: "Phone",
  model: "phone",
  required: true,
  placeholder: "Digite seu número de telefone",
  validator: VueFormGenerator.validators.string,
  cleaveOptions: {
   phone: true,
   phoneRegionCode: "pt-BR"
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you must import cleave like this depends on how to and where to use it

```
import cleave from 'cleave.js'
```

correct your code type is wrong
it must be like this
`type: 'cleave'` (there is no 'r' at the end)

you can not use the validator with the cleave type
no need to input-Type also

try this:

```
{
  type: "cleave",
  label: "Phone",
  model: "phone",
  required: true,
  placeholder: "Digite seu número de telefone",
  cleaveOptions: {
   phone: true,
   phoneRegionCode: 'US'
  }
 }
```